# How to return empty rectangles in python?

Tags: python

I have a 150*150 big rectangle.
After executing some algorithm i get a bunch of small rectangles that are positioned inside the big one using coordinates `[x1,y1,x2,y2]` => `x1,y1` coordinates of left bottom point, `x2,y2` coordinates of top right point.

Example:

[image]

Here are the coordinates for each colored rectangle:

```
[[0, 0, 5, 5], [0, 5, 10, 15], [0, 15, 10, 25], [0, 25, 10, 35], [0, 35, 15, 50], [0, 50, 15, 65], [0, 65, 15, 80], [0, 80, 15, 95], [0, 95, 15, 110], [0, 110, 15, 125], [0, 125, 15, 140], [10, 0, 25, 15], [10, 15, 25, 30], [15, 30, 30, 45], [15, 45, 40, 70], [15, 70, 40, 95], [15, 95, 40, 120], [15, 120, 40, 145], [25, 0, 50, 25], [40, 25, 65, 50], [40, 50, 65, 75], [40, 75, 65, 100], [40, 100, 65, 125], [40, 125, 65, 150], [50, 0, 75, 25], [65, 25, 90, 50], [65, 50, 95, 80], [65, 80, 95, 110], [65, 110, 95, 140], [95, 50, 140, 95], [95, 95, 140, 140], [90, 0, 140, 50]]
```

Is it possible to retrieve the coordinates of the empty white spaces?

Comment: Would you be open to using some sort of geometry library?  (Shapely comes to mind, although I've never used it myself, and make no claim that it's best for the job.)  The basic approach would be to start with the full rectangle, subtract each colored rectangle from it, and see what's left.

Comment: Your question doesn't state what defines a colored rectangle. You just said the four digits in the list corresponds to dimensions, so how about the colored data?

Comment: @jasonharper thanks for the response i will try to use the `difference` and see how i can manage a solution. For anyone needing a sample code: [link on codefile](https://codefile.io/f/XAob7hNpaX)

Comment: @surge10 the four data points(coordinates) are for the colored rectangles as i said in the first sentence `[x1,y1,x2,y2]` => `x1,y1` coordinates of left bottom point, `x2,y2` coordinates of top right point. so for example the first data point `[0, 0, 5, 5]` is a rectangle where the 4 points are `(0,0),(5,0),(5,5),(0,5)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jasonharper comment i managed to find a solution using `shapely`

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#The big rectangle 
mainR = Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 150), (150, 150), (150, 0)])

#The small colored rectangles
rects = [[0, 0, 5, 5], [0, 5, 10, 15], [0, 15, 10, 25], [0, 25, 10, 35], [0, 35, 15, 50], [0, 50, 15, 65], [0, 65, 15, 80], [0, 80, 15, 95], [0, 95, 15, 110], [0, 110, 15, 125], [0, 125, 15, 140], [10, 0, 25, 15], [10, 15, 25, 30], [15, 30, 30, 45], [15, 45, 40, 70], [15, 70, 40, 95], [15, 95, 40, 120], [15, 120, 40, 145], [25, 0, 50, 25], [40, 25, 65, 50], [40, 50, 65, 75], [40, 75, 65, 100], [40, 100, 65, 125], [40, 125, 65, 150], [50, 0, 75, 25], [65, 25, 90, 50], [65, 50, 95, 80], [65, 80, 95, 110], [65, 110, 95, 140], [95, 50, 140, 95], [95, 95, 140, 140], [90, 0, 140, 50]]

#Creating a polygon of each small rectangles than subtracting it from the big rectangle
for rect in rects:
    point1 = (rect[0], rect[1])
    point2 = (rect[2], rect[3])
    rectangle = Polygon([point1, (point2[0], point1[1]), point2, (point1[0], point2[1])])
    mainR = mainR.difference(rectangle)


#Ploting the remaining shapes
fig, ax = plt.subplots()    
for polygon in mainR.geoms:
    x1, y1 = polygon.exterior.coords.xy
    ax.plot(x1, y1, color='blue', label='rectangle')
    
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Image:

[image]